# Can't DROP NOT NULL from postgreSQL command

Tags: sql, postgresql, notnull

I try to use this command to DROP the NOT NULL from `"name"` column,  but it's get stunned and not return anything.

```
ALTER TABLE "school_students" ALTER COLUMN "name" DROP NOT NULL;
```

Here's my `"school_students"` table structure:
[image]

UPDATE 1:

After running query `select now() - query_start, pid, query from pg_stat_activity where state != 'idle' order by 1 desc;` to check if uncommitted transaction exist, here's the result:

[image]

Please help, thanks.

Comment: does your statement run without errors?

Comment: Does an uncommitted transaction exist? ALTER TABLE needs a ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on the given table.

Comment: @TheFool yes, it just stunned.

Comment: @DominikKlug how can i know if the uncommitted transaction exist?

Comment: @arutar Nope, i've try it but not success, stunned as the same command above.

Comment: what does stunned mean?

Comment: To see current queries `select now() - query_start, pid, query from pg_stat_activity where state != 'idle' order by 1 desc;`

Comment: @TheFool mean nothing returned, nothing happened, it just stand there.

Comment: @arutar I've update the question with the result of that query, please check.

Comment: after you get the pid of the stucked query, you can end it `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid);`

Comment: @arutar thanks, your idea is worked and get answered by Laurenz Albe in below comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that can block a short operation like this is a conflicting lock.

An `ALTER TABLE` statement like the one you are running requires a (short) `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table – you cannot change the table definition while it is in use. Now any concurrent transaction that has ever used the table holds at least an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on the table until the transaction ends, and that will block your `ALTER TABLE`.

To find out which session blocks you, do this:

- Before you run `ALTER TABLE`, execute

  ```
  SELECT pg_backend_pid();
  ```

  to find out your session process number.
- Run the `ALTER TABLE` that hangs.
- Start another database session and run

  ```
  SELECT pg_blocking_pids(12345);
  ```

  where 12345 is the result from the query above. Now you know which sessions are blocking you.
- Close the blocking transactions and try again.  To forcibly end a hanging transaction, you can use

  ```
  SELECT pg_cancel_backend(23456);
  ```

  where 23456 is a process number found in the previous statement.

You should fix all bugs in the application that keep transactions open.  This is **always** a bug.  If you have no better way, set the database parameter `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` so that transactions that stay open too long get closed by the server.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked. `SELECT pg_backend_pid();` to select blocked command and `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(23456);` to remove blocked command resolved my issue.